# Database Connection not closing

Tags: java, mysql

What's the reason why my database connection won't be closed?
The error says that there are too many connections when i perform several queries

Thanks in advance, here's the code:

```
   try {
        st = DBConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        st.setString(1, userID);
        result = st.executeQuery();
        checker = !result.first();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            DBConnector.getConnection().close();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

here's my DBConnector class by the way

```
public class DBConnector {
    private static Connection;
    private static String host;
    private static String username;
    private static String password ;


    public static void setUsername(String newusername){
        username = newusername;
    }
    public static void setPassword(String newpassword){
        password = newpassword;
    }
    public static void setHost(String newHost){
        host = newHost;
    }
    public static void setConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(host, username , password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
    public static String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public static String getHost(){
        return host;
    }
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        setConnection();
        return conn;
    }

    public static void disconnect(){
        conn = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there an exception?

Comment: try removing try and catch block inside finally block

Comment: You could try extending your class to implement the AutoClosable interface ( providing your using Java 7 ) so you can take advantage of try-with-resources 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: when i perform several queries, it says that there are too many connections meaning that the connections that i used in the were not closed. Also, closing the connection requires a try catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your class correctly, you create a new connection that is closed immediately in your `finally` block instead of closing the original one when you do `DBConnector.getConnection().close()`.

Change your code to:

```
 Connection connection = DBConnector.getConnection();
 try {        
     st = connection .prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
     // more code
  } catch (...) {
     // more code
  finally
    {
        try {
            connection.close(); // 
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

Even better is to use try-with-resources (Java 7):

```
 try (Connection connection = DBConnector.getConnection()) {        
     st = connection .prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
     // more code
 } catch (...) {
     // more code
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to iterate over my answer several times, but now it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you open and close your connection properly.

```
/**
 * Creates a connection to database if there isn't any established.
 * 
 * @return {@link Connection} to database.
 */
protected Connection getConnection() throws ServiceException{
    try{
        if(this.conn == null || this.conn.isClosed()){
            // Here you have to create your connection
            // this.conn = ...
        }
        if(conn==null){
            // Retry to connect in case that the connection is still null!
            Thread.sleep(250);
            getConnection();
        }
    }catch(SQLException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}


/**
 * Closes the {@link Connection} to database.
 */
protected void closeConnection(){
    try{
        if(this.conn != null && !this.conn.isClosed()){
            this.conn.close();
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        this.conn = null;
    }
}
```